# Best Website to record logs like progress, errors, bugs, requests

Tags: ios

I am looking for a website, where I can invite all my developers 
 and they can create a log of the apps they are making . 
I will also be inviting tester for same project so that they can also create a bug log, or report error and request a developer to look and examine it. 
basically I want a website to record logs, errors related to apps and have a communication among developer and tester .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/) should help you. This service have bugtracker, platform for testing, analytic services and much more.